# Timeline/Schedule View using QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm trying to implement a Timeline View (more specifically, a schedule) which looks like this: 
http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/5369/schedulek.png

I tried implementing it with nested ListViews, where the the main ListView is Vertical and its child ListViews are the horizontal programs.
Navigating left or right the view updates the ContentX of each child (Not sure its very efficient..)
Navigating up or down should get the coordinates of the current position of the highlight in the list and highlight the appropriate item in the ListView below (or above)..

I'm not sure if this solution is efficient enough.. 
if you see a better way implementing this please comment..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I'd think of a Flickable (with horizontal only) plus a Column of ListViews. Keep the nested ListViews static and only use the Flickable for scrolling.

Comment: Thanks mauricek. The Flickable should be shared between the ListViews?, do you have an example maybe?